# how to get php session array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a problem to get in a session array from php into a javascript, I tried to do it with json_encode, but I got problem with that since json not take swedish charatar and I need to have it in the array, any other suggestion how to do it!

I´m setting the sessions array here, the print_r is only for checking so it´s correct

```
while($row2[]=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
$_SESSION['row2'] = $row2; 
print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][0]);
print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][1]);
print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][2]);
```

and in my javascript i tried this

```
var row2 =<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['row2']) ?>;
console.debug(row2);
```

Comment: JSON will work if you're using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: try using console.log instead of alerting.  it will show up in firebug and chrome.  it also will show you object properties and array members not just single variable like alert.

Comment: Are these two code snippets in same file or different files?

Comment: if i use UTF-8 encoding I got problem with swedish charactar, and sorry for the alerts, now replaced

Comment: They are in same file, and the problem is that i want to use swedish character. Without them it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: Tell your database-client that you expect the data to be encoded as UTF-8 when you request/fetch it from the database. You do this by setting the client character encoding, see [`mysql_set_charset`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset).

When you retrieve the data encoded as UTF-8 you can use it with `json_encode` and your website script's can properly receive it.